# Math formula for first person 3d game

Tags: python, math, 3d, panda3d

I want to make a first person 3d game but I can't set the camera formula right.

So I have a rotation: 0 to 359. Next the x,y coordinates, z remains the same.

Camera rotation : 0 - front, 90 - left, 180 - back, 270 - right but I can adapt it

What is the formula for the camera ?

Platform: Panda3d, python, opengl

Thank you

Comment: If you could post a code sample, and explain what it should do, and what it *actually* does, it might be easier to answer.

Comment: Don't you have up/down rotation of the camera too? Usually one calculates the rotations from where the camera is and where it is looking at.

Comment: Yes, but what is the formula for that ?

Comment: Well the api usuallyprovides the means to just put in the lookat and the position and uses matrix mathon the whole of the scene to calculate the next matrix in levels. There are three matrix levels in graphics programming, World, View and Projection. I don't know the panda3d api, but as opengl includes the ability to calculate the next matrix for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, it looks like you need a Doom style camera movement, i.e., no up-down turns. Consider this:

1. You need to render the "world" as seen through the camera.
2. Assuming positive x is to the right and positive y is to your front, when the camera moves to the right the world's image moves to the left.
3. When the camera turns positively to the left, the world's image turns to the right.

Now, let's try to construct the equations:

1.First, translate the world coordinates to the camera's position:

```
Xwt = Xw - Xc;
Ywt = Yw - Yc;
Zwt = Zw;

(Xc,Yc,Zc) = camera position
(Xw,Yw,Zw) = world coordinates of object in the scene
(Xwt,Ywt,Zwt) = world coordinates of object translated to camera position
```

2.Now, rotate the translated coordinates by an angle opposite to the camera's rotation:

```
Xwc =  Xwt * Cos(psi) + Ywt * Sin(psi);
Ywc = -Xwt * Sin(psi) + Ywt * Cos(psi);
Zwc =  Zwt

Psi = angle of camera rotation
(Xwc,Ywc,Zwc) = world coordinates of object transformed to camera orientation
```

You can combine the two steps and transform it to a matrix form.